# cant run ejabberd on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, xmpp, ejabberd

I installed ejabberd on an ec2 instance, however I am facing multiple problems running it

1. when I use my ip/5280/admin or ip/5280 i dont recieve a response.
   The other thing in my conf file i chose my host: ip (xx.xxx.xx.xx).
   When I check the status of ejabberd i recieve ejabberd@localhost is
   started with status : started
2. The other thing when I run netstat I cant see that ejabberd is connected or running
3. finally I check ejabberd log file. It has the following error:  No certificate found matching 'pubsub.ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal': strictly configured clients or servers will reject connections with this host; obtain a certificate for this (sub)domain from any trusted CA such as Let's Encrypt (www.letsencrypt.org)

Any help will be apprieciated. I am running the latest version of ejabberd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3. finally I check ejabberd log file. It has the following error: No certificate found matching

Don't worry, that's a warning, I also get it and it doesn't break ejabberd.
The important thing is to have something like this:

```
...
12:33:00.546 [info] ejabberd 18.04.107 is started in the node ejabberd@localhost in 8.10s
12:33:00.551 [info] Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:5280 for ejabberd_http
12:33:00.551 [info] Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:5269 for ejabberd_s2s_in
12:33:00.552 [info] Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:5222 for ejabberd_c2s
12:33:00.552 [info] Application ejabberd started on node ejabberd@localhost
```

> 2. The other thing when I run netstat I cant see that ejabberd is connected or running

Maybe you are looking at the established connections, not the listening ports? This is my client connected to remote servers:

```
$ netstat | grep xmpp
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.14:39299      cookie.ziri:xmpp-client ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.14:41867      lb.jabb.im:xmpp-client  ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.14:33063      ec2-52-50-2:xmpp-client ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.14:39769      cookie.ziri:xmpp-client ESTABLISHED
```

And this is what you want to see, this is ejabberd listening for xmpp connections:

```
$ netstat -l | grep xmpp
tcp6       0      0 [::]:xmpp-client        [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:xmpp-server        [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

> 1. when I use my ip/5280/admin or ip/5280 i dont recieve a response. The other thing in my conf file i chose my host: ip (xx.xxx.xx.xx).

It's host:port/admin, not host/port/admin. See:

```
$ wget -S --user=user1@localhost --password=mypass11 http://localhost:5280/admin/
--2018-06-28 12:39:19--  http://localhost:5280/admin/
S'està resolent localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
S'està connectant a localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5280... conectat.
HTTP: s'ha enviat la petició, s'està esperant una resposta... 
  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 333
  WWW-Authenticate: basic realm="ejabberd"
Authentication selected: basic realm="ejabberd"
S'està reutilitzant la connexió a localhost:5280.
HTTP: s'ha enviat la petició, s'està esperant una resposta... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 1803
Mida: 1803 (1,8K) [text/html]
S'està desant a: «index.html»

index.html                     100%[==================================================>]   1,76K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2018-06-28 12:39:19 (85,8 MB/s) - s'ha desat «index.html» [1803/1803]

$ head index.html 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http....
```

Comment: I also got same issue but still it is not resolved. Can you please help? @Badlop also getting No certificate found matching.